# Django - Retrieve all manytomany field objects related to a specific model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have my models **reviews** and **news**, both having a manytomany relation with **Category** model.
Now I want to get all the categories associated with only one of these two models. For example, to get all categories associated with **News** model, I tried querying database with `News.categories.all()` but got `AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'objects'`.

**News Model:**

```
class News(models.Model):
    ...
    categories = models.ManyToManyField("articles.Category", related_name="news")
    ...
```

**Reviews Model:**

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
    ...
    categories = models.ManyToManyField("articles.Category", related_name="reviews")
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to retrieve objects through the Category model.
You can filter on the related name on the Category model.

Try `Category.objects.filter(reviews__isnull=False)` or `Category.objects.filter(news__isnull=False)`

Comment: I got the idea, but there is a problem here. Your suggested query excludes categories associated with both models. I think the answer needs to be changed a bit. The desired query would be `Category.objects.filter(reviews=True)` or `Category.objects.filter(news=True)`.

Comment: I don't think it does though, because `Category.objects.filter(reviews__isnull=False)` will return all categories linked to a `Reviews` models, regardless of whether `news` is null or not

Comment: Just tested it. Your answer is works just fine. Thanks for help.